# Operate on the y's of a {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...{xn,yn}} list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've been scratching my head and I can't figure out a way to conveniently apply an operation to the y values of a list of the form`{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...{xn,yn}}`. The list is in this form for plotting with *ListPlot[]* mostly. 
The type of operations I'd like to apply would include:

- Mathematica Operations. Ex.: `LowpassFilter[y's]` (not point-by-point, I know)
- Generic mathematic point-by-point operations. Ex: `y's*10 + 2`

I know I can transpose and then filpity-flop turn the list arround and then target each element, and then transpose back and flopity-flip and overwrite the original list. This becomes tiresome after dealing with each case. I bet there is a cleaver way to do this. Or what would be the best way to hold values in a list that can easily be plotted and manipulated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      Map[{#[[1]],2+10 #[[2]]}&,{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...{xn,yn}}]


      MapAt[2+10#&,{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...{xn,yn}},{All,2}]
```

if you need to operate on the 'y' list as a list, do like this:

```
      Transpose@MapAt[LowpassFilter[#,1]&,
         Transpose@{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...{xn,yn}},2]
```

Comment: That's it, I guess. The `f[y's]` works very well, like `2+10*y's`. But `LowpassFilter[y's]` doesn't unfortunatelly, because this functions expects a single dim array like `{y1,y2,y3...}`. In that case one should use `LowpassFilter[ array[[All,2]] ]` and replace the values in the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you named your list as `l`, i.e.

`l={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...{xn,yn}}`

You can get all `y`s by:

`ylist=l[[All,2]]`

Comment: That allows me to get the y's, but then I need to do `Transpose[ { l[[All,1]], I[[All,2]]*10+2 }]` to get a corrected `l`. I guess this notation is not bad and I can always define it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

`{#, 10 # + 2} & @@@ lst`

> {{x1, 2 + 10 x1}, {x2, 2 + 10 x2}, {xn, 2 + 10 xn}}